# My 2003 Dodge grand carvan

Tags: starting

MY van has been doing this thing where I'll go to start it and I have to turn the key 5 or 6 times before it turns on. (note) it does make one clicking sound everytime I turn the key to start it (until the battery dies).. but does nothing. When I put jumper cables on it, it'll still make the clicking sound everytime but it'll turn on after about 5 or 6 times turning the key on and off.

Comment: someone told me I might have to replace the ground wire.... because thats a problem with dodge's from that era

Comment: Have you tested the battery itself?

Comment: If the battery is good, it might be a problem with the battery terminal connections, or a relay. I've never had a wire itself go bad - but often the connections on the ends of the wires will get corroded and need to be cleaned.